# save multiple entries simultaneously to a single core data entity by using a loop

Tags: swift, loops, core-data, instance

My swift code below features a func that saves a string to core data. The problem it is only saving the UserDBObj.setValue closets to the end of the code not both. So it is only saving one a time. I want RDC and aa to be saved simultaneously. In the debug area only “aa” is seen when printed. Some stated to solve this just Loop over your values and create a new instance of Users for each value.

```
func openDatabse()
{
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    saveData(UserDBObj: newUser)
}

func saveData(UserDBObj: NSManagedObject)
{
    UserDBObj.setValue("RDC", forKey: "username")
    UserDBObj.setValue("aa", forKey: "username") 
    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed")
    }
    fetchData()
}
```

Comment: You are setting two values for the **same** key. Of course the second line overwrites the first.

Comment: @vadian how do I make it so both can be saved I do something like saveData2(UserDBObj2: newUser2)

Comment: You need two *newUser*s